# Operation is not supported on this platform for Stimulsoft report in .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, report, stimulsoft

I'm using C# WPF in .NET Core 6 and Visual Studio 2022.

I have added `StiReport.dll` to my project, but I got error for this code :

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var report = new StiReport();
    var pathreport = @"C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\Gozaresh\Gozaresh\BUGETRP.mrt";

    report.Compile(); //→ Error : System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'
    report.Render();
    report.Show();
}
```

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.

It works fine on .NET Framework 4.7.2 !

Comment: Well - so it works on .NET 4.7.2 - but that doesn't guarantee that it'll work on .NET 6 !! The error says as much - if it's not working on .NET 6 and isn't supported by its makers, you're probably out of luck ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StiReport library is not supported in the .NET Core 6 platform. There are various reporting solutions available that support .NET Core, such as Telerik Reporting, Syncfusion Report Platform, or Stimulsoft Reports.Net Core,

Try using Stimulsoft Reports.Net Core.Install the Stimulsoft Reports.Net Core NuGet package.

Add the necessary using statements to import the Stimulsoft namespaces:

```
using Stimulsoft.Report;
using Stimulsoft.Report.Wpf;
```

To create and display a Stimulsoft report. Here's an example:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var report = new StiReport();
    var pathToReport = @"C:\Path\To\Your\Report.mrt"; // Replace with the actual path to your report file
    report.Load(pathToReport); // Load the report file

    var reportViewer = new StiWpfViewer();
    reportViewer.Report = report;
    reportViewer.Show();
}
```

Comment: thanks , Is there any way I can add it to .NET Core as a .NET Framework interface project?

Comment: You can create a separate .NET Standard library project that serves as an interface or wrapper for the .NET Framework project. This way, you can indirectly use the functionality of the .NET Framework project dll within your .NET Core project.